# Blazor gRPC use Windows-Authentication

Tags: blazor, blazor-server-side, blazor-webassembly, grpc-web

I am using Blazor gRPC and have currently 3 projects. A .Client, a .Server and a .Shared project.
I build it like this example shows: https://github.com/hakenr/BlazorGrpcWebCodeFirst

I want to have Windows-Authentication because my server uses the Windows username and interacts with a SQL DB to get user roles and so on. This is already implemented.

Now i want to activate the DefaultAuthentication for my HttClientHandler to get the user information in the service which is in the .Server project. When i currently do this:

```
    var httpClientHandler = new HttpClientHandler();
    httpClientHandler.UseDefaultCredentials = true;

    var httpHandler = new GrpcWebHandler(GrpcWebMode.GrpcWeb, httpClientHandler);

    return GrpcChannel.ForAddress(backendUrl,
        new GrpcChannelOptions { HttpHandler = httpHandler });
```

I get this exception:

```
System.PlatformNotSupportedException: Operation is not supported on this platform. at System.Net.Http.BrowserHttpHandler.set_Credentials(ICredentials value)
```

Then i tried to set the RuntimeIdentifier in the project file of the .Client (.Server and .Shared already have this RuntimeIdentifier set) like this:

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <RuntimeIdentifier>win-x64</RuntimeIdentifier>
</PropertyGroup>
```

But with this i get another error at startup because there is no dotnet.js file in my '_framework' folder.

Can i get the WindowsAuthentication work somehow else or can i do anything to create the dotnet.js file?

Thanks for all the help!

I set the UseDefaultCredentials:

```
    var httpClientHandler = new HttpClientHandler();
    httpClientHandler.UseDefaultCredentials = true;

    var httpHandler = new GrpcWebHandler(GrpcWebMode.GrpcWeb, httpClientHandler);

    return GrpcChannel.ForAddress(backendUrl,
        new GrpcChannelOptions { HttpHandler = httpHandler });
```

I tried to set the RuntimeIdentifier

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <RuntimeIdentifier>win-x64</RuntimeIdentifier>
</PropertyGroup>
```

Comment: Remove HttpClientHandler and just use the injected HttpClient. Blazor WASM runs on the browser and the actual HTTP connections are made by the browser, not HttpClient. Windows authentication is performed the very first time the browser makes a request to the server, including downloading the WASM files.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I registered a HttpClient as scoped. Do you say that i should use this HttpClient and set it direclty in the GrpcChannelOptions? If i do it like this i get the following Exception  **Unhandled exception rendering component: Status(StatusCode="Internal", Detail="Bad gRPC response. Response protocol downgraded to HTTP/1.1.") Grpc.Core.RpcException**

Comment: I got it work by starting the Service in IIS